# matching a date/timestamp with a regex

Tags: regex, scala

I wrote the following regex to match date strings looking like:

```
2019/01/02 08:20:19
```

the regex  is `val reg = "([\\d]{4})/([\\d]{2})/([\\d]{2}) ([\\d]{2}).*.r"`

The Scala function is:

```
val dateExtraction: String => Map[String, String] = {
  string: String => {
    string match {
      case reg(year, month, day, hour) =>
                 Map(YEAR -> year, MONTH -> month, DAY -> day, HOUR -> hour )
      case _  => Map(YEAR -> "", MONTH -> "", DAY -> "", HOUR -> "")
    }
  }
}
val YEAR = "YEAR"
val MONTH = "MONTH"
val DAY = "DAY"
val HOUR= "HOUR"
```

I want to get the year, month, day and hour from the regex.
But the date above is not parsed as expected and I get a null result. Any idea how to fix this, please.

Comment: Why not use something like `val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    println(format.parse("2019/01/02 08:20:19"))`?

Comment: I wrote it in the function

Comment: No I shall use a regex actually

Comment: You got your `.r` inside the  double quotes. It should be outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `java.time` for such a problem, like:

```
  val input = "2019/01/02 08:20:19";
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
  val dt = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(input)).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())

  dt.getYear() // 2019
  dt.getMonthValue() // 1
  dt.getDayOfMonth() // 2
  dt.getHour() // 8
```